# Parametros en clases anonimas

Tags: java, poo

Tengo el la siguiente clase anonima

```
ActionListener seleccionYo= new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae, Hero hero, Yo yo){

            hero = new Yo("Oscar", 2, 0, 1000, 50, 25, 5, false,
                    new HealingFlask("Flask", 5, "This potion heals hp and ether."));
            hero.setHp(600);
            hero.setEther(45);
            hero.setPosX(8);
            hero.setPosY(19);
            }
            };//fin clase
            seleccionarYo.addActionListener(seleccionYo);
```

Al ponerle nuevos parametros (Hero hero, Yo yo) no me permite hacer override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuándo sobre-escribes un método, sea en una clase anónima o no, debes respetar la *firma* del método que estás sobre-escribiendo. **Esta es la base sobre la que *funciona* el [polimorfismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica))**, que es una de las principales *características* de la POO.

La *firma* es, la cantidad, tipo y orden de los parámetros que recibe el método. Por simplicidad y para explicar el concepto, voy a poner un ejemplo con clases declaradas, no olvides que es lo mismo con clases anónimas.

Supongamos que tenemos una clase, declarada de esta manera.

```
class Lenguaje
{
   public void saludarA(String nombre)
   {
      System.out.println("funcionalidad de saludo no definida " + nombre);
   }
}
```

Esta debiera ser una clase abstracta, pero por aquí la dejo con el método implementado por si el lector no va tan *avanzado* en java. El programador avanzado, sírvase disculpar mi atrevimiento.

La idea es declarar varias clases que hereden de `Lenguaje`, por ejemplo `Espaniol` e `Ingles`, pero en determinado momento, tener un método que actúe polimórficmente en ellas, por ejemplo una iteración sobre una colección de *Lenguajes*, algo como:

```
    Collection<Lenguaje> lenguajes = new ArrayList<Lenguaje>();

    collection.add(new Espaniol());
    collection.add(new Ingles());
    collection.add(new Aleman());

    Iterator<Lenguaje> iterator = lenguajes.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       iterator.next().saludarA("Juan");
    }
```

Esto eventualmente imprimiría a consola algo como:

```
Hola Juan
Hello Juan
Hallo Juan
```

Es por esta razón que java, y en general, los lenguajes OOP, exigen que las clases descendientes, al sobre-escribir los métodos, respeten la firma. De esta manera, la *lógica* detrás de llamar el método y pasarle la lista de parámetros es la misma, sin importar a que *altura* de la jerarquía esté la clase que implementa el método. Hasta ahora no conozco un lenguaje compilado que resuelva esto de otra manera, para permitir que eventualmente se puedan pasar otros parámetros que la clase ancestro no conoce.

Para el curioso, una posible clase descendiente sería como esta:

```
class Espaniol extends Idioma
{
   @Override
   public void saludarA(String nombre)
   {
      System.out.println("Hola " + nombre);
   }       
}
```

Advertencia: Puede que el código no compile, está puesto como ejemplo, lo he escrito directamente en el navegador. La idea es dar un ejemplo para la lectura de un *humano*, no de un compilador.

A la larga tu *clase anónima*, no es muy diferente de esta clase. Es un tipo de *azucar sintáctica*, para ahorrarte tener que escribir la declaración de una clase completa. Pero por detrás, es una clase como cualquier otra. Si lo piensas un poco, en esta caso, se basa en el polimorfismo, tal como lo he mostrado en el ejemplo, para que se ejecute el código que cualquier persona del planeta pueda escribir cuando ocurre una *acción* cualquiera en una aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por la información

Answer (score 0):

Cuando sobrescribes un método debes respetar los parámetros originales, esto es, si actionPerformed recibe un parametro del tipo ActionEvent, al sobrescribirlo también deberá recibir únicamente un parametro de ese mismo tipo.

Comment: Gracias por la información